# daily sales report with PHP Mysql CASE

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get the daily sales report based on below query..

This is my Table structure

```
orderid resid   payment_type    ordertotalprice orderdate
1       10      cod             50              2016-06-14 
2       10      cod             10              2016-06-14
3       10      creditcard      40              2016-06-14 
4       10      cod             30              2016-06-14
5       10      creditcard      20              2016-06-14 
6       10      cod             10              2016-06-14
7       10      creditcard      20              2016-06-14 
8       11      cod             10              2016-06-14
```

I need the output result below using above table.

```
resid total_orders_cnt total_sales total_orders_cash total_sales_cash   total_orders_cc total_sales_cc
10    7                180         4                 100                    3               80
11    1                10          1                 10                     0               0
```

I'm using below query, But its not getting exact result what i want.

```
SELECT COUNT(orderid) AS total_orders_cnt, SUM(ordertotalprice) AS total_sales,
        SUM(CASE WHEN (payment_type= 'cod') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_orders_cash,
        CASE WHEN (payment_type= 'cod') THEN SUM(ordertotalprice) ELSE 0 END AS total_sales_cash,
        SUM(CASE WHEN (payment_type = 'creditcard') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) total_orders_cc,
        CASE WHEN (payment_type = 'creditcard') THEN SUM(ordertotalprice) ELSE 0 END AS total_sales_cc
FROM order WHERE resid='10' AND orderdate = '2016-06-14';
```

So pls anyone help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please mark one answer per question if they are the problem solver and you approve. You do this with the  [Green Check mark](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234), like Giorgos' below or any of your others. None of your questions, pushing 20, have been accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(orderid) AS total_orders_cnt, 
       SUM(ordertotalprice) AS total_sales,
       SUM(CASE WHEN payment_type = 'cod' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_orders_cash,
       SUM(CASE WHEN payment_type = 'cod' THEN ordertotalprice END) AS total_sales_cash,
       SUM(CASE WHEN payment_type = 'creditcard' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) total_orders_cc,
       SUM(CASE WHEN payment_type = 'creditcard' THEN ordertotalprice END) AS total_sales_cc
FROM order 
WHERE resid = '10' AND orderdate = '2016-06-14';
```

Comment: @mikejohnvino Glad I was able to help. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.